# Adding a unique ID to each sub-menu

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I have the following menu via header.php:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'container' => false,
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'items_wrap' => '<ul class="header__nav-items header__nav-items--primary">%3$s</ul>',
    )
);
```

For parent menu items with children, I'm replacing the `<a>` tags with a button (controlled by ACF). Here's the function:

```
<?php
function edit_menu_item($item_output, $item) {
    if ( get_field( 'dropdown', $item) == 'yes' ) { 
        return '<button aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="aria-'.$item->object_id.'" class="header__button">'.$item->title.'</button>';
    }
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el','edit_menu_item', 10, 2);
```

When the button is clicked, the `aria-expanded` attribute switches from `false` to `true`. The sub-menu is also revealed. This is controlled via JavaScript.

With the above functions, this is what's produced on the front-end.

```
<ul class="header__nav-items">
    <li class="menu-item-has-children header__nav-item">
        <button aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="aria-1880" class="header__button">Food</button>
        <ul class="sub-menu header__sub-menu header__sub-menu--toggled">
            <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="/pizza" class="header__nav-anchor">Pizza</a></li>
            <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="/burgers" class="header__nav-anchor">Burgers</a></li>
            <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="/fries" class="header__nav-anchor">Fries</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The `aria-controls` attribute has a unique ID. This ID needs to match up to my sub-menu.

How would I add a unique ID to each sub-menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can know about menus in WordPress - handlers use menu arguments. You can try to use this.

Using the argument filter, we can pass the ID of the item:

```php
add_filter(
    'nav_menu_item_args',
    function( $args, $item, $depth ) {
        $args->item_id = $item->ID;

        return $args;
    },
    10,
    3
);
```

Then use custom argument anywhere.

```php
add_filter(
    'walker_nav_menu_start_el',
    function($item_output, $item) {
        if ( get_field( 'dropdown', $item) == 'yes' ) { 
            return '<button aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="submenu-'. $item->ID . '" class="header__button">' . $item->title . '</button>';
        }
        return $item_output;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

```php
class My_Nav_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

        // Default class.
        $classes = array( 'sub-menu' );

        // ! Get parent item ID:
        $id = isset( $args->item_id ) ? ' id="submenu-' . absint( $args->item_id ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
         *
         * @since 4.8.0
         *
         * @param string[] $classes Array of the CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', $classes, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        // ! Insert ID:
        $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul{$class_names}{$id}>{$n}";
    }
}
```

It remains to include the file with an custom walker
and point it to the menu:

```php
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'container' => false,
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'items_wrap' => '<ul class="header__nav-items header__nav-items--primary">%3$s</ul>',
        'walker'  => new My_Nav_Menu_Walker()
    )
);
```

I have not tested the code. In some cases there can be a conflict and you can either use `clone` for the menu argument, or use another way to limit the scope of an custom argument.

Comment: You nailed it, thank you! Hopefully WordPress introduces a much simpler way to do this in the future.

Comment: No one solution out of the box can create all possible menu options. The menu in WordPress is one of the best components. Developers can implement custom output with simple and straightforward solutions. WordPress has downsides, but it's not a menu.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was a great help.